# Django Admin 500 internal server error

Tags: python, ubuntu, django, python-3.x, sqlite3

Деплою приложение на Django с использованием gunicorn и при переходе в /admin (он уже добавлен в urls.py) админская страница редиректится на /admin/login и я получаю 500 error от nginx, никаких объяснений. Gunicorn тоже ничего не сообщает.

Базу данных пока что использую sqlite3, специально делаю chmod 777, но и это не помогло. Как поступить? На локалке все работало.

Вот settings.py:

```
   """
    Django settings for Some project.

    Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.8.1.

    For more information on this file, see
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/

    For the full list of settings and their values, see
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/
    """

    # Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
    import os

    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


    # Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
    # See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

    # SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
    SECRET_KEY = 'some key'

    ADMINS = (('Some name', 'Some email'),)

    # SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
    DEBUG = True

    TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

    ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
        '*'
    ]

    # Application definition

    INSTALLED_APPS = (
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'Some app name'
    )

    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
        'Some app name.exception_middleware.ProcessExceptionMiddleware' # этот middleware возвращает HttpResponse с описание ошибки, если status_code == 500. Не помогло.
    )

    ROOT_URLCONF = 'Some project name.urls'

    TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]

    WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Some project name.wsgi.application'


    # Database
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        }
    }


    # Internationalization
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

    LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

    TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

    USE_I18N = True

    USE_L10N = True

    USE_TZ = True


    # Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

    STATIC_URL = '/static/'

    STATIC_ROOT = 'Path to static root'
```

Comment: посмотрите, что падает в error_log nginx, бывает, ему просто буферов не хватает для отображения целиком

Comment: @Etki
`6965 rewrite or internal redirection cycle
while internally redirecting to "/index.html", client: some client, server: some site, request: "GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1", host: "
some site"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело было в конфиге nginx. Так как хостились на Laravel Forge, где по умолчанию php стоит (так вышло), то в конфиге вместо того, чтобы просто передавать запрос gunicorn, он еще выполнял `try_files`. После того, как убрали, все заработало.